# Strict decoding error after running "kubectl build .yaml" command

Tags: linux, azure, kubernetes, kubectl

Before anything else, let me give you a .json file which contains info regarding my Azure File Storage;

```
{
    "identity": {
        "type": "None"
    },
    "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS",
        "tier": "Standard"
    },
    "kind": "StorageV2",
    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionid>/resourceGroups/quantumworkspacek8s/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/quantumworkspacek8s",
    "name": "quantumworkspacek8s",
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
    "location": "eastus",
    "tags": {},
    "properties": {
        "defaultToOAuthAuthentication": false,
        "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
        .
        .
        "allowCrossTenantReplication": true,
        "privateEndpointConnections": [],
        "isNfsV3Enabled": false,
        "isLocalUserEnabled": true,
        "isSftpEnabled": false,
        "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_2",
        "allowBlobPublicAccess": true,
        "allowSharedKeyAccess": true,
        "isHnsEnabled": false,
        "networkAcls": {
            "bypass": "AzureServices",
            "virtualNetworkRules": [],
            "ipRules": [],
            "defaultAction": "Allow"
        },
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
        "encryption": {
            "services": {
                "file": {
                    "keyType": "Account",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "lastEnabledTime": "2024-02-18T05:08:10.8469432Z"
                },
                "blob": {
                    "keyType": "Account",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "lastEnabledTime": "2024-02-18T05:08:10.8469432Z"
                }
            },
            "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
        },
        "accessTier": "Hot",
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "creationTime": "2024-02-18T05:08:10.6750734Z",
        "primaryEndpoints": {
        .
        .
        .
        },
        "primaryLocation": "eastus",
        "statusOfPrimary": "available"
    }
}
```

And now, the following is my "integrated" .yaml file while which contains the information of pod, pv, pvc, storageclass, as well as the Azure secrets.

```
# Define the pod (or the persistent volume, PV) for creating a pod in kubernetes, as well as the volume mount and the persistent volume claim (PVC).
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: quantumworkspace
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000  # Replace with appropriate UID
    runAsGroup: 1000  # Replace with appropriate GID
    fsGroup: 1000  # Replace with appropriate GID
  containers:
  - name: quantumworkspace
    image: elijun831/quantumworkspace:1.0.0
    command: ["jupyter", "lab", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--allow-root"]
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8888
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m # The minimum spec of CPU for an application to run; you can change this value.
        memory: 128Mi # The minimum spec of memory for an application to run; you can change this value.
      limits:
        cpu: 250m # The maxiumum spec of CPU for an application to run; you can change this value.
        memory: 256Mi # The maxiumum spec of memory for an application to run; you can change this value.
    volumeMounts:
    - name: azurefile
      mountPath: /mnt/azure # Path to the directory where the files will be mounted; please replace "/path/to/directory" with the actual path using "pwd" command in the terminal.
      readOnly: false
  volumes:
  - name: azurefile
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: azurefile
---
# Define the PV
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: azurefile
  labels:
    storage: azurefile
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: azurefile
  azurefile:
    secretName: azure-secret
    secretNamespace: default
    shareName: azurefile
    readOnly: false
  mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0644
  - file_mode=0664
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
  - mfsymlinks
  - nobrl
---
# Define the PVC.
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: azurefile
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi # The amount of storage you want to allocate for the files; you can change this value.
  storageClassName: azurefile
---
# Define the storage class.
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: azurefile
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS # The SKU name of the storage account; you can change this value (e.g., Standard_LRS, Standard_GRS, Standard_RAGRS, Premium_LRS, or Premium_ZRS).
  location: eastus # The location of the storage account; you can change this Azure region (e.g., eastus, westus, southcentralus, westeurope, eastasia).
  storageAccount: quantumkubernetesk8s # The name of the storage account; make sure to set the storage in your Azure subscription.
  secretName: azure-secret
  secretNamespace: default
---
# Define the secret as well as your Azure credentials.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: azure-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  azure_subscription_id: <subscription-id-decoded-in-base64>
  azure_tenant_id: <tenant-id-decoded-in-base64>
  azure_client_id: <client-id-decoded-in-base64>
  azure_client_secret: <client-secret-decoded-in-base64>
  azurestorageaccountname: <azurestorageaccountname-decoded-in-base64>
  azurestoragekey: <azurestoragekey-decoded-in-base64>
```

I ran the command `kubectl apply -f /home/elijun9831/testing/quantumworkspace/templates/pv.yaml` and it give the error like this:

```
pod/quantumworkspace created
persistentvolumeclaim/azurefile created
storageclass.storage.k8s.io/azurefile created
secret/azure-secret unchanged
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "/home/elijun9831/testing/quantumworkspace/templates/pv.yaml": PersistentVolume in version "v1" cannot be handled as a PersistentVolume: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.azurefile"
```

I asked Gemini and ChatGPT for analyzing the error; they gave me possible solutions - such as indentations issue and security context - and I applied them and reran the same command. Unfortunately, I keep seeing the same error regarding the "strict decoding error".

What are the problems, and how can I resolve them so that the pv, pvc, and a kube pod could be generated without any errors?

Comment: Consider using a StatefulSet, if you really need persistent storage; in most cases you should not manually create Pods or PersistentVolumes.  In [this example](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/azure_file/azure-pv.yaml#L14), `azureFile:` has a capital `F` and that would cause the validation error you see.